# "has been" or "have been" is the right grammar

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I always get confuse where precisely I should use "Has been" and "Have been".
For example, to respond to my client related to a issue reported few days back:

> "This report problem has been resolved"

or

> "This report problem have been resolved"?

Some of my friends use "Have been" on similar scenarios.

Comment: *This report problem* is a ***singular*** noun phrase, so you must use the singular verb form ***has***. You'd use the plural if you were saying ***These** report **problems** have been resolved*.

Answer (score 3):

*Has* is third person singular. So, if you have a subject at the third person singular(*hint: you can replace the subject with he, she or it*), you say *has been*. Otherwise, you say *have been*.

In your example, *this report **problem*** is the subject. Do you see a plural ending (*s, -es, etc.*)? No, so it is singular. Does it refer to *you* or *I*? No, so it is third person singular. Therefore, *This report problem ha**s** been resolved.*

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pattern:

She has
He has
It has
Report has

They have
We have
Reports have

You are referring to one problem, so the correct way would be:
The reported problem has been resolved.